# Blueprint array of objects (apiary)

Tags: api, blueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I'm trying to describe array of objects with syntax based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29833106/2210960)

```
+ Response 200 (application/json)
    + Attributes
        + time (object, required)
            + default (string, required) - `HH:MM` default time
            + times (array, required) - Array of times for date
                + time (object)
                    + value: 12:00 (string, required) - `HH:MM` time value
                    + occupied: true (boolean, required)
```

But what apiary renders is

```
{
   "time": {
   "default": null,
   "times": [
        {
         "undefined": null
        }
   ]
}
```

Is it bug or I got it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSON support is still in beta, and will be able to handle those cases in the upcoming weeks.

You can safely describe your structures this way, and documentation will catch up soon.